# Java Implementing interface Comparable, comparing manually entered data with generated data

Tags: java, double, comparable, compareto

**Question: How to I directly compare manually entered student infomation (shown below = 'Elise') with other student Aggergate marks, then sort the data with the largest 'Aggergate' number at the top of the output file.**

```
 public class Student2 implements Comparable<Student2> {

@Override
   public int compareTo(Student2 o) {
        return Double.valueOf(this.aggerate()).compareTo(Double.valueOf(o.aggerate()));
     if (result > 0) {
         return 1;
         } else if (result < 0) {
         return -1;
         } else {
         return 0;
         }
         }


public static void main(String... args) {
Set<Student2> Stu = new TreeSet<>(
                    Comparator.comparing(Student2::aggregate).reversed()
                              .andThen(Student2::getId));
    Stu.add(new Student2(25321, "Elsie", 51.5, 45.6, 48.5, "3rd", "Proceed To Stage 2"));
    Stu.stream().forEach((c) -> {
        System.out.println(c);
    });
}

public double aggerate() {
    DecimalFormat decFormat = new DecimalFormat("#.#");
    double aggerateMarks = Double.valueOf(decFormat.format((IR101Grades +  IR102Grades) / 2));
    aggerateMarks = Math.round(aggerateMarks * 100.0) / 100.0;
    return aggerateMarks;

}
public String toString() {
    return "\n" + studentID + " |" + studentName + "\n" + "IR101: " + IR101Grades + " | " + "IR102: " + IR102Grades + " |"
            + " Aggregate Mark: " + aggerate() + "\n" + "Class: " + setGrade() + " | " + "Outcome: " + setClass()
            + "\n" + "\n" + "-----------------------------------------------------" + "\n" + "\n";
}
```

Comment: I suggest you reduce the code to just the bits which compile. Oh, and don't forget to ask a question if you want to get an answer.

Answer (score 1):

To create a TreeSet which reverse sorts by aggregate you can do

```
Set<Student2> Stu = new TreeSet<>(
                        Comparator.comparing(Student2::aggregate).reversed()
                                  .andThen(Student2::getId));
```

This way your tree will be in reverse order.

Note: just in case two students have the same aggregate, the getID should ensure they are never considered a duplicate

Comment: Hello, first off; thanks for taking the time to answer. I am still new to java and very confused with using compable. I've refined and changed the code and my question to be more direct and precise, since your input is helpful but my code however is still not working.

Comment: @KazNevermore What do you mean by "not working"? It doesn't even compile. In your first method you have code after your `return` and I suggest you read your compile messages and fix them all.